# SharePoint and OpenPGP file encryption

Tags: sharepoint-online, security

If I have SharePoint on an azure cloud which can be accessed from any computer using a browser, is it possible to integrate client side PGP encryption so when files are uploaded, they are encrypted client side and then stored in SharePoint, and when files are downloaded or opened, they are decrypted client-side and encrypted again before uploading/saving?

Ideally, I'd like to set it up so the encryption and decription happens automatically if the clientside has the OpenPGP keys, but that might be pushing it.

Answer (score 2):

Implement SSL and on the SQL side, TDE. You can also encrypt the Azure disks (ADE). What you're asking for isn't feasible and better solved via other means that make your environment more secure as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

That is true for sure, but in some circumstances (here: German public service Compliance Requirements) it is necessary to use the encryption as mentioned by the requester

Comment: I don't feel safe without client side open source encryption.  Really dislike having to blindly rely on closed source server side encryption.